# Tweepy: Adjusting JSON output

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, tweepy

I am using this code to extract Tweets with the Search API. So far, I managed to extract only the whole JSON with jsonpickle. However, I would like to extract only specific information from the JSON, like the `tweet.id`, `tweet.full_text` or `tweet.favorite_count` and store it in a CSV file. Does somebody know how I could modify the code for this purpose without changing the `max_id`/`since_id` structure?

```
import sys
import jsonpickle
import os
import tweepy

consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                   wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)

searchQuery = 'XXXX' 
maxTweets = XXX # number of tweets one wants to extract
tweetsPerQry = 100  # the max tweets the API permits per query
fName = 'tweets_keyword' # storing the tweets in a text file
sinceId = None
tweets = []

max_id = -1
tweetCount=0
print("Downloading max {0} tweets".format(maxTweets))
with open(fName+".csv", 'w') as file:
    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
        try:
            if (max_id <= 0):
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry, lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended')
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry, lang = 'en',tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            else:
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry,lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1))
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry,lang = 'en',tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found")
                break
            for tweet in new_tweets:
                file.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) +
                        '\n')
            tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
            print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # Just exit if any error
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            break

print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fName))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Status`/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) itself has attributes for the information in question.
You can simply use those instead of the raw JSON.

The raw JSON is represented as a dictionary, as is standard, so you can also just access it by key as you would any other dictionary.

Also, at no point will `API` ever be falsey.